# Excel - finding unique number of value based on ID/column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a table that looks like the following:

| ID | Company |
| --- | --- |
| 123 | ABC |
| 123 | DEF |
| 123 | ABC |
| 456 | ABC |
| 456 | ABC |

I want to insert a new column that tells me how many unique company's are associate with each ID. So ideally something like this:

| ID | Company | Count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | ABC | 2 |
| 123 | DEF | 2 |
| 123 | ABC | 2 |
| 456 | ABC | 1 |
| 456 | ABC | 1 |

That way I can just filer out the 1 value and only have the 2 (or more) left to focus on. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Did you try COUNTIFS?

Comment: I have, but it's not populating correctly... its giving a count of 2 for each except the 123 DEF combination... perhaps I'm using it incorrectly.

Comment: Maybe instead of saying you tried, share how you tried (formula you used). Better in the question than as comment

Comment: Thanks for the call-out. I used "=COUNTIFS($E$16:$E$20,E16,$F$16:$F$20,F16)"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have Excel 365 you can use this formula:

`=ROWS(UNIQUE(FILTER([Company],[ID]=[@ID])))`

I used a table with the according column headers

It first selects all companies belonging to the row ID, returns them as unique values and counts them

Comment: I thought COUNTIFS would lead to the solution, but then I saw your post and couldn't help but trying it out and I noticed that the problem was more complicated than I first thought: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SW3Of.jpg A well deserved upvote from my side. Instead of ROWS one could also use COUNTA.

Comment: Can you provide more guidance on the square brackets and the @ sign? I'm not sure how to utilize those in the formula.

Comment: I also don't believe I have Excel 365.

Comment: I think I got it to work for me: =ROWS(UNIQUE(FILTER(K:K,H:H=H2))) where K:K refers to the Company column. H:H refers to the ID column. And H2 is the first cell with the ID.

Comment: As I said: I used a table (select your data, goto Insert > table) --> with that you can use structured reference ([] to reference columns by name; @-sign references the cell in the same row. It is worth learning about those tables as they make formulas more readable plus a lot other advantages :-) - by the way: if the answer helped you, it would be great if you mark it as solved